# How to use express method app.use with Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have a node/express app that works locally. I've deployed it to Heroku. All routes declared in index.js file work, but all the route wrapped in a dedicated router can't be reached.

The code is self-explanatory:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import connectToDatabase from "./database/connection";
import userRouter from "./routers/user";
import { SocketControler } from "./controllers/socket";

// Server
export const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.CLIENT,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

// Middleware
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: [process.env.CLIENT as string] }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
SocketControler.manageEvents(io);

// THESE ROUTE WORK
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("<h1>homepage</h1>");
});

app.get("/hello", function (req, res) {
  res.send("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
});


// ALL THESE ROUTE RETURN 404 BUT WORK LOCALLY
// Routers
app.use(userRouter);
app.locals.io = io;

// Start
connectToDatabase()
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
      console.log(`server is listening on ${process.env.PORT}!`);
    })
  )
  .catch((err) => console.log("error", err));
```

The routes wrapped in routers look like this:

```js
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();
import getUser from "../routes/user/get-user";

router.get("/user", getUser);

export default router;
```

How to allow app.use on Heroku?

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Anything printed out there?

Comment: Yes, the logs confirm that the server is listening. When sending a request to `www.my-app.heroku.com/user`,  I receive a 404, and the logs confirm that a request to `user` was received, but returned a 404.